# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable: why?

Tags: python, list

```
from difflib import get_close_matches

order_output = {
    "initiate ion drive" : "Initiating the ion drive.",
    "run" : "Running",
    "eat" : "Eating",
    "enter coords to" : "Settings coords to:"
}


orders_list = ["initiate ion drive", "eat", "run", "enter coords to"]

def ord_input():
    order = input()
    order1 = get_close_matches(order, orders_list)
    order2 = ''.join(map(order1, order_output))
    if order:               ^#the problem
        print(order_output[order1])
    else:
        print("Don't know this order.")

ord_input()
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/order.py", line 16, in <module>
    ord_input()
  File "C:/Python34/order.py", line 11, in ord_input
    order2 = ''.join(map(order1, order_output))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I want to convert that specific list string to a regular string.

How can I do that?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the problem line? It's certainly not how you're meant to use map.

Comment: how can I convert order1 to a regular string?

Comment: Why do you want to convert `order1` to a string? You can't `map` a string to a list, can you?

Comment: I need to convert order1 so I can use it to index the dictionary. I think I made a mistake by using map

Comment: Your error says `'list' object is not callable` because `get_close_matches` returns a `list` and `map` expects a function as its first parameter. Therefore, `map` is "calling" a `list` like a function, which is your error

Comment: do you know how to turn order1 to a regular string? that would be very helpful

Comment: You need to either index the list or loop over `order1` to get "regular strings"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments and other answers, `get_close_matches` returns a list. Maybe try looping over the matches and check if it is in your dictionary.

Also, really not sure what this line was supposed to achieve since you can't `map` anything other than a function and `order2` wasn't used.

```
order2 = ''.join(map(order1, order_output))
```

Anyways, here is what I think you should be doing

```
from difflib import get_close_matches

order_output = {
    "initiate ion drive" : "Initiating the ion drive.",
    "run" : "Running",
    "eat" : "Eating",
    "enter coords to" : "Settings coords to:"
}


orders_list = ["initiate ion drive", "eat", "run", "enter coords to"]

def ord_input():
    order = input('Order: ')

    matches = get_close_matches(order, orders_list)
    for m in matches:
        if m in order_output:
            print(order_output[m])
        else:
            print("Don't know order {}.".format(m))

ord_input()
```

Comment: but when I have done that, it generated for me an error

Comment: I couldn't explain as well as this site. https://pyformat.info/... It is just basic string formatting. I find it easier on the eyes than `"string" + "string"`

Answer (score 1):

`difflib.get_close_matches` returns a list. The `map` builtin takes a *function* as its first argument, and applies it to each element of the iterable that is the second argument. So you're trying to call a list as a function, which is a `TypeError`. A list is not callable.

If the goal is to index the `order_output` dictionary, just do so directly.

```
order2 = order_output[order1]
```

Comment: but I need to turn order1 into a regular string. that's my top goal

Comment: The return value from `input()` _is_ a string. You can use it directly to index the dictionary, but you should use a try/catch block in case the user's input is not actually a key in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The map() function takes two arguments: a function and an iterable such as a list. On line 11, you put a list returned by the get_close_matches function, as an argument when the first argument is supposed to be a function. For more information on the map() function go to:https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map.